# many identical Exist queries on ActiveRecord save?

Tags: sql, activerecord, model

I have a table with 200,000 rows.

When I do an insert/update via an ActiveRecord model, I see close to 20 identical Exist queries taking nearly 100ms each!

```
Domain Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."name" = 'sgsgroup.in' LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
Domain Exists (90.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "domains" WHERE LOWER("domains"."name") = LOWER('sgsgroup.in') LIMIT 1
Domain Exists (89.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "domains" WHERE LOWER("domains"."name") = LOWER('sgsgroup.in') LIMIT 1
Domain Exists (91.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "domains" WHERE LOWER("domains"."name") = LOWER('sgsgroup.in') LIMIT 1
[...]
Domain Exists (89.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "domains" WHERE LOWER("domains"."name") = LOWER('sgsgroup.in') LIMIT 1
Domain Exists (89.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "domains" WHERE LOWER("domains"."name") = LOWER('sgsgroup.in') LIMIT 1
SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "domains" (....
```

I already have "name" index on the Domain table. Any ideas what's happening here and how to optimize these record updates?

Also, is it normal to have identical queries like these on a record update?

Comment: `90.7ms` isn't "nearly 1 second", it's nearly 1/10th of a second.

Comment: it is not normal, need to see the code whre you are inserting the record.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. It's very strange. I restarted the console and now the same exact update/save uses a single query as opposed to 20. I'm at a complete loss as to what it may have been.

Comment: So I finally figured out the root cause. The issue was due to me manually loading (and reloading) my models in the console. A separate DB query was being generated by ActiveRecord for each instance of the loaded model code. Why was I reloading my models? Because I had config.threadsafe! in application.rb which prevented me from using reload! .. fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it could be to do with a case-insensitive validation of uniqueness on the name. Subsequent executions ought to be cached though -- don't know why they're not.

You might like to see if your RDBMS support creating an index on LOWER(name), as it's possible that a regular index on name is not being used.

Comment: Thanks David - yes, I think you're absolutely right on the root cause of the 100ms query time. Any ideas why there are lots of identical queries being issued?

Comment: Thanks David - accepting your answer and please see my response to tihom above.

Comment: What we'd call a "transient issue", I guess!

Comment: The issue, duplicate queries, appears to reappear and progressively get worse as the application runs. When I restart rails (Webrick) it starts off w/ one query but